# Run slideshow dynamically back and forwards with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, reverse

I have a DIV container and inside I have child images.
something like this structure:

```
<div class="look-down">
  <img src="look-down-1.jpg">
  <img src="look-down-2.jpg">
  <img src="look-down-3.jpg">
  <img src="look-down-4.jpg">
  <img src="look-down-5.jpg">
</div>
```

All images are hidden with either display:none; or - opacity: 0;

Now I have a button: "Run Animation" and "Run Animation Backwards"

```
<button id="animate-images">Run Animation</button>
<button id="animate-images-reverse">Run Animation Backwards</button>
```

Upon click on "Run Animation" I'd like to loop through all images and starting from the first and move next to the second revealing the next photo.
basically it will show "frame by frame" animation which I can control the pace

Upon clicking "Run Animation Backwards" I would like to the the same just backwards. basically reverse the animation

2 important things:

- I need it to be dynamic so I can add / remove images
- I need to control how many seconds/mili seconds between each image

I created a starter Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hamergil/jdg1fy9q/30/

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Hey @gil hamer, thanks for setting up the quiz for us. But would be easier if you may help us by adding code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: In the fiddle you don't provide much code, it seems you didn't try anything so far.. Also what do you mean by dynamic, that you can change the images in your slideshow during runtime any time you want?

Comment: @wiesion  I updated the fiddle. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the opacity of images with `.each()` iterator function:

```
  $('.lookdown img').each(function() {
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    delay += 500;
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ow0Lu21h/

Comment: that's almost exactly what I need. anyway how to avoid the delay on the first click?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var delay = 0;
var pace = 1000;  // 1 second
  $('.lookdown img').each(function() {
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, pace);
    delay += pace;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the approach of delayed animations over a image loop you will run into a lot of problems and edge cases, mostly because of the option to reverse the animation. Easiest way to avoid all potential issues is to use a different animation principle: By working with a window interval and constantly asking for the current animation direction, you can ensure the animation integrity.

In my code I am working with timeouts, which will give you the chance to have a much faster polling interval when the animation is paused - but while it is running, it always waits for a transition to complete before changing direction.

```
var intv = function() {
  if(direction === 0) return window.setTimeout(intv, interval);
  var next = position + direction < 0 ? images.length - 1 : position + direction >= images.length ? 0 : position + direction;
  $(images[position]).fadeOut(transition);
  $(images[next]).fadeIn(transition);
  position = next;
  return window.setTimeout(intv, showtime + transition);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jdx0zufa/

You can change this code to different behaviors by just changing the `next` calculation - e.g. when it has reached the end and is running forward, change the direction to backward, etc.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. is it possible to make it not looping and avoid the opacity effect? meaning that it will look more "show" and "hide like frame by frame animation? Thanks

Comment: Starting from here, it should not be that difficult to make those changes yourself